# Chrome search multiple webpages

Tags: chrome, search

I looking for a way how to search multiple pages simultaneously. For example, I looking for some product "my product" and I want chrome to open shop1,shop2,shop3 and search the "my product" on them.

something like extension what takes my input "my product" and open multiple links (link to shop with getting param "my product".

A long time ago there was an extension of instant multi-search but it does not work anymore. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I think it's a good Q for folks on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Go to google and type in **keyword site:URL1 OR site:URL2** as you need. As shown in the figure below

[image]

There is also a Chrome extension called "Multiple Tabs Search". It opens multiple URLs or searches for several words using a configured search engine, each one in a new tab. You can use it too